# Stored function execution fails using TADOStoredProcedure

Tags: sql-server, delphi, sql-server-2008-r2, delphi-xe2

I have a very simple function in SQL Server 2008 R2, which I am calling using `TADStoredProcedure`.

The function is defined as follows:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[GetNextAvailableNo] 
(
    @APrefix nvarchar(10)
)
RETURNS int
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @Result int
    SELECT @Result = MAX([No])+1 FROM [Table1] WHERE [Prefix] = @APrefix
    RETURN @Result    
END
```

I am facing a weird problem. The first time that I try to call this function, I get this error:

> exception class   : EOleException
>   exception message : Line 1: Invalid procedure number (0). Must be between 1 and 32767.

And by the first time, I mean the first time after SQL service has started. After that, everything works fine. At first I thought this is an issue with my SQL Server 2008 R2 installation, but I'm seeing this problem on every installation available to me.

Has anyone got any idea?

Comment: @bummi Not really. It's at most 3 characters

Comment: What is the Max[NO]+1, is it more than 32767?

Comment: @Ravaut123 Doesn't matter. I get the same error even if `Table1` is empty. And, only for the first call to the function after SQL Server service start

Comment: also if you test it only in the sqlserver do you have the error

Comment: @Ravaut123 No. If I execute `SELECT dbo.GetNextAvailablePatNo('XX')` in SQL Server Management Studio after service restart, then my application runs normal.

Comment: My guess is this is an issue with Delphi wrapper for `ADOCommand`, but I'm puzzled as to why this occurs immediately after service restart.

Comment: This is not a store procedure but a function. Add your function to a store procedure and call the store procedure or in a TAdoQuery add 'SELECT dbo.GetNextAvailablePatNo('XX')'

Comment: try using ";1" when calling from Delphi

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the function in a selection statement.

Like

```
<TAdoQuery>.Sql.Add('SELECT dbo.GetNextAvailablePatNo('+QuotedStr('XX')+')');
```

for optimalitation to the server:

```
const
  cNextAvailablePatNoScript='SELECT dbo.GetNextAvailablePatNo(:Param)';

...
<TAdoQuery>.Sql.Text:= cNextAvailablePatNoScript;
<TAdoQuery>.Parameters.ParamByName('Param').Value:= 'XX';
<TAdoQuery>.Open; 
...
```

Comment: <TAdoQuery>.Sql.Add('SELECT dbo.GetNextAvailablePatNo(:Param);